# Long running windows service with a memory leak? Or just looks like one?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

This sounds a little odd, but I'm not sure if my process has a memory leak or not, and I was hoping to get some information.

I was recently assigned an investigation into why a windows service in production was consuming roughly a gig of ram (the server it is running on has 8 gigs).  This is outside of my experience as a developer, but it's been a very good chance for me to read up on how garbage collection is working on msdn and other sources.  But at this point I'm very confused about /when/ collection actually runs, on this point, ever article I read is vague.

1) I have found a specific operation that increases memory by ~30kb each time it is executed.
2) I have very carefully gone over the code and believe that I am properly closing everything, and removing references
3) I have used several memory profilers, all of them seem to indicate that my old objects are linked to the gc.
4) If I leave the process absolutely idle for a few days, the memory usage suddenly plummets down to ~8 megs

So based on this, I'm not even sure I have a memory leak.  Given that GC is an expensive process, is it possible that I grew to 1 gig in production just because there was still free ram to be had, and acquiring it was "cheaper" than running GC?  Especially given that this service is run ~6 times a second?  If this is the case, what options do I have?  I am of the understanding that I cannot forceably trigger GC, do I have any resort?

Thank you for any input you might have, I realize memory leaks and gc in csharp is a deep topic and if there's a particularly helpful read on the subject, I'd be happy to be pointed that way as well.

Comment: Any insight or code you can share as to what the service is actually doing?  It's pretty hard to be helpful without that.  Also, just because of the fact that it takes up 1GB of ram does not necessarily mean it's leaking.  Let's look at this the other way -- how much memory SHOULD it be taking up?

Comment: Bryan, when I run the service in my development or integration environment, it takes roughly 10 megs in the working set, ~70 megs in the private bytes.  It is also restarted all the time as the environment isn't really that stable.  In the QA environment, it takes around 30 megs in the working set, and ~70 in private bytes.  However I notice that the QA environment is also always sitting at about 95% memory usage, so I thought perhaps we were bumping into constraints and triggering more frequent GCs. out of characters... QA is sadly very different from prod in terms of frequency of execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly CAN force a garbage collection - just call GC.Collect. It's not that you can't but that the garbage collector usually does a better job of figuring out when it should run than you do. But here, you can call it explicitly - as a debugging tool - to see whether or not the allocated memory is eligible for collection.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen that API linked before.  I'm giving it a whirl now, although I guess I might still have the option that whatever strange condition triggered a leak in prod is just a condition I'm missing in dev.  Still if I can keep this thing stable at a tiny number across environments, it would go a long way towards an explanation.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because I was able to use it to show that under a load test, memory usage held constant on all of our primary use cases.  It seems weird that it would ever grow that large, so I also increased logging in case some odd alternate code path lead to the leak, I'll at least be able to figure it out next time it happens.  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Memory leak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx) usually implies that memory is never deallocated and process eventually crashes with [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx). You are saying that it does get deallocated after a while

> 4) If I leave the process absolutely idle for a few days, the memory usage suddenly plummets down to ~8 megs

You certainly can force garbage collection using [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx). But as others have said it is not a good long term solution. I highly recommend you to read about garbage collection in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045). If you still convinced that you have memory leak you can create a dump of the process in production environment using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). And analyze it later using [WinDbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx). Unless you can use [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) on production which would be a lot easier.